# Powershell scripts going to sleep

Tags: multithreading, powershell, multiprocessing

I have a powershell script which loops over each file in a folder and does a lot of "high-computation" tasks on each of these files. I have multiple instances of this script running on my system.

I do use a write-host before starting each of these tasks to see when these tasks start and end.

I started these instances of the script last night and when I came today morning I noticed that some of my powershell terminal were stuck at a write-host command and when I pressed ENTER they wrote that content to terminal and continued the preocessing.

It looks like some of these terminals go to sleep. Why am i seeing this and how can i prevent this?

Comment: If the "quick edit" option is enabled for a console window and it receives a mouse-click event, the OS suspends the window for text selection.

Comment: So you are saying that I clicked on the powershell window, because of which it was in a halted state?

Comment: This "QuickEdit" sounds like an anti-feature to me. It has certainly caused lot of weird behavior and head scratching. I did not even consider the possibility that somebody would knowingly implement such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "QuickEdit" option in the "Windows PowerShell" Properties window.

[Right click the PowerShell window to get the to the Properties window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPsqH.png)